# TailwindCSS classnames does not override

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm coding a Button component in ReactJS which receives some props for styling it. for example `primary`, `rounded` and `outline`. I join classNames with the `className` function which comes from "classnames" library.

```
import className from 'classnames'

interface ButtonProps {
    children: any // Elements that placed in the Button
    outline?: boolean // Adds outline to the Button, removes background color and change font color
    rounded?: boolean // Adds border radius to the Button
    primary?: boolean // Adds blue background color to the Button
    [key: string]: any // Add some more props for example event handlers
}

function Button({
    children,
    outline,
    rounded,
    primary,
    ...rest
}: ButtonProps) {

const classNames = 
    className(
        'flex items-center select-none px-3 py-0.5 border border-2 font-medium',
        {
            'text-white bg-blue-600 border-blue-600': primary,
            'rounded-lg': rounded,
            'text-blue-500 bg-transparent': outline && primary,
        },
        rest.className
    )

return (
        <button {...rest} className={classNames}>
            {children}
        </button>
    )
}
```

when I set `primary` prop alone, the Button will appear like this:

[image: primary Button]

and classnames from the browser inspector is `flex items-center select-none px-3 py-0.5 border border-2 font-medium text-white bg-blue-600 border-blue-600`
which is true and what we expect. but when I add `outline` along with `primary` prop, the Button will appear like this:

[image: primary outline Button]

and classnames is `flex items-center select-none px-3 py-0.5 border border-2 font-medium text-white bg-blue-600 border-blue-600 text-blue-500 bg-transparent`

as you can see, `bg-transparent` and `text-blue-500` comes after than `bg-blue-600` and `text-white`, then must override them. according to the pictures, `bg-blue-600` will be overrided by `bg-transparent`, but `text-white` does not overrided by `text-blue-500`.

this screen comes from CSS styles part of Developer tools:
[image: CSS styles of the Button]

why this happen and how can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I guess the previous `primary` value is overriding to `outline && primary` value that's why the `test-white` is appearing to you, not `text-blue-500`

Comment: and your class `text-blue-500` does not get purged? With dynamic class changes you could have the issue that it got purged and therefor it does not exist

Comment: @nuser137 thanks for your time, but I don't think so because `bg-transparent` from `outline && primary` overrides `bg-blue-600` from  `primary`. And in classnames of `outline && primary`, `bg-transparent` and `text-blue-500` is after than their corresponding classnames in `primary`. I suspect that this problem is only related to css.

Comment: @bill.gates thanks, but `text-blue-500` exists in classnames after than `text-white`

Comment: @MJDevelops yea it exist on the html element, but does the class `text-blue-500` exists in general? You can apply `randomclass` on an element and it wont do nothing because the class `randomclass`does not exist.

Comment: @bill.gates yeah it does. and one point another is that in browser developer tools, when I inspect the button element, the property `rgb(59 130 246 / var(--tw-text-opacity))` exists in it's CSS styles which is due to `text-blue-500` but it's crossed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not apply multiple class names that apply the same property on the same element with the same variant at the same time. With `outline` and `primary` truthy values, you'll get conflicting `text-white` and `text-blue-600` as well as conflicting `bg-blue-600` and `bg-transparent`. Instead only apply of these at any one time, like:

```js
const classNames = 
    className(
        'flex items-center select-none px-3 py-0.5 border border-2 font-medium',
        {
            'border-blue-600': primary,
            'text-white bg-blue-600': primary && !outline,
            'rounded-lg': rounded,
            'text-blue-500 bg-transparent': outline && primary,
        },
        rest.className
    )
```

Comment: I really appreciate you 

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "dedupe" version to achieve what you want.
This version of classNames will override existing classes.
Simply add "/dedupe" in your import :

```
import classNames from "classnames/dedupe";
```

https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#alternate-dedupe-version